# Extracting XML elements from a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios, uiwebview

I'm writing a Bible Memory app for the IPhone and I need some help with picking out verses displayed in a UIWebView.

I have an xml file which is read into the UIWebView, and I need to be able to tell when a user taps on a specific verse. Here's a sample of the xml file:

```
<bible translation="KJV">
<testament name="Old">
    <book name="Genesis">
        <chapter number="1">
            <verse number="1">In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.</verse>
            <verse number="2">And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.</verse>
            <verse number="3">And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.</verse>
            <verse number="4">And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.</verse>
            <verse number="5">And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day.</verse>
```

In relation to the code above, if the user taps "In the beginning..." the program needs to know (at least) that the user just clicked a "verse" element and its "number = 1".

**=================== EDITED ==========================**

Here's my proposed solution..type..thingy. 
Let me know how it sounds.

I still have the UIWebView reading the XML file. It is also being formatted my a CSS file in the bundle. Since UIWebViews take note of links (hrefs) [thanks Jonathan] I can add verse numbers in front of each tagged verse (I know its a little tedious, but I was planning on doing it anyway :)

This way, the xml file will look like this:

```
<bible translation="KJV">
<testament name="Old">
    <book name="Genesis">
        <chapter number="1">
            <n>1</n><verse number="1">In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.</verse>
            <n>2</n><verse number="2">And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.</verse>
            <n>3</n><verse number="3">And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.</verse>
            <n>4</n><verse number="4">And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.</verse>
            <n>5</n><verse number="5">And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day.</verse>
            <n>6</n><verse number="6">And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters.</verse>
            <n>7</n><verse number="7">And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so.</verse>
```

I'll either use css to force the 'n' tag as a link or just put 'href' elements instead. 
This way, when the verse number, which will be shown before the verse, is tapped, I can fire a custom method to figure out where I am (what verse I'm in).
Here's a post I found about intercepting the firing of links in the UIWebView:
http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/iphone-sdk-tip-firing-custom-events-when-a-link-is-clicked-in-a-uiwebview/

I'm hoping this will work, its a little ad-hockish.. but programs often begin that way. 
Anyone try something like this before?

Don

Answer (score 0):

The UIWebView delegate only responses to links (hrefs), so this might be a problem. In theory you could work around this by doing some hit-detection, but it would be more advisable (plus you'll sleep better at night :D ) to parse the XML and load it into a UITableView, much more maintainable and wayyyy more user friendly.

Comment: You know... getting some good sleepy time in is important :)

The UITableView, unless I don't know enough of how to tweak it, may be a bit challenging in the look and feel of the app. The verses will often overlap and be on the same line and having each on in its own table cell may appear blocky. I am in the process of finishing an xml parser, though, so if there is a way to get the contiguous look of a UIWebView into a UITableView, I'm open to it.
I wasn't aware, though, that UIWebViews took notice of links. This is a good thing as I also had a plan for this. I'll post my idea up in a sec.

Comment: Use NSXMLParser to parse the XML. Learn how to parse XML first, then try to figure out how to use it with a UITableView. You can't try to learn how something works while trying to shoehorn it into a problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: You're right. I started putting together the xml parser using NSXMLParser to build a Bible object with Testaments->Books[]->Chapters[]->Verses[]. This will come very handy with the UITableView when I want to display a list of verses by themselves. 

I want to use the UIWebView, though, to display the bible itself like this:
http://www.ebooktechie.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/iphonebibleapp.jpg

This way, the verse #s will be links with info on the upcoming verse and the rest of the text will be regular 'verse' elements.